# q{} removing spaces in a raku map

Tags: hex, rgb, raku

This Raku expression converts color codes from RGB to HEX:

```
raku -e 'my @array = (0, 255, 0), { @^a «+» (25.5, -25.5, 0) } ... ( * ~~ (255, 0, 0 ) ); 
         say @array.map: "#" ~ *.fmt: "%02X"'
(#00 FF 00 #19 E5 00 #33 CC 00 #4C B2 00 #66 99 00 #7F 7F 00 #99 66 00 #B2 4C 00 #CC 33 00 #E5 19 00 #FF 00 00)
```

Adding q{} to the expression removes spaces:

```
raku -e 'my @array = (0, 255, 0), { @^a «+» (25.5, -25.5, 0) } ... ( * ~~ (255, 0, 0 ) ); 
         say @array.map: "#" ~ *.fmt: "%02X", q{}'
(#00FF00 #19E500 #33CC00 #4CB200 #669900 #7F7F00 #996600 #B24C00 #CC3300 #E51900 #FF0000)
```

I have not been able to figure out why adding 'q{}' to the expression removes spaces. I would aprreciate any hint on this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [the doc for `.fmt` applied to a `List`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/fmt#class_List), the routine's signature is:

```
method fmt($format = '%s', $separator = ' ' --> Str:D)
                                        ▲▲▲ - default separator
```

So, by default, each three element `List` like `(0, 255, 0)` will turn into three formatted elements separated by a space when you don't specify the separator, but unseparated when you specify a null string as the specifier.

`q{}` is a string (using [the `Q` lang](https://docs.raku.org/language/quoting)) that specifies a null string (ie it's the same as `''`).

Hence the result you're seeing.

Comment: I had a look at the syntax Q documentation, but failed to see the equivalence between q{} and ''   :O.  Thanks very much for your hint! :)

Comment: @Mimosinnet you can maybe raise an issue there?

Comment: @Mimosinnet Glad to be of help. Do you think your failure to see the equivalence was due to the lack of mention of `q` and `qq` in the opening paragraph; or the more general issue that the introduction to `q` doesn't say "the `q` form of `Q` ..."; or that it's visually difficult to discern the `q{...}` example in among the `q[...]` examples, and/or something else?

Comment: I appreciate the concern. My mistake lied in understanding Q syntax as "something you do to strings" instead of "a string". Therefore, I missed seeing q{} as an empty string and, instead, I was looking to some obscure block syntax :O. ¡Mil gracias! :)

Comment: @Mimosinnet Thanks for clarifying. Yeah, that makes a lot of sense. Raku lets folk choose a huge range of delimiters for strings including some that are strongly associated with anything but strings. But from hereon you'll hopefully remember that if you see `Q`/`q`/`qq` in prefix/listop position, you're almost certainly looking at a string.